# ngram is not working properly always is unigram

Tags: r

I am doing text mining.  I want to do ngram but it is doing as unigram always.

```
# myprogram
library(tm)
library(ngram)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
library(RWeka)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

setwd('F:/My files/specification')
df<- read.csv('spec.csv')
test<- Corpus(VectorSource(df$doc1))
test <- tm_map(test, tolower)
test <- tm_map(test, stripWhitespace)
test <- tm_map(test, removeNumbers)
test <- tm_map(test, removePunctuation)
test <- tm_map(test, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
test  <- tm_map(test, stemDocument, language = "english") 
test  


tok <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=2, max=10))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(test,control = list(tokenize = tok))
termFreq <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
termFreqVector <- as.list(termFreq)
test2 <- data.frame(unlist(termFreqVector), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
setDT(test2, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
setnames(test2, 1, "term")
setnames(test2, 2, "freq")
test3 <- head(arrange(test2,desc(freq)), n = 30)

ggplot(data=test3, aes(x=reorder(term, freq), y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + coord_flip()
```

## ....................................................................

It is my program. I saw in some questions I have to install 0.6-2 tm package version, I tried but it is not available for R version 3.5.0.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem isn't from tm package because I got answer with crude data.my data is a csv file with 15 rows and 5 columns.15 documents are devided in 5 sections so what is my data problem?